# Is there a table which lists invalid triggers?

Tags: sybase-asa

I am trying to unload a schema of Sybase ASA 9 and it goes till 90% + but then it gives me an error when creating triggers:

> `adjusted_amount` is not found

It doesn't tell me which trigger is referencing this column. Is there any way to find which trigger is referencing this column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
select trigger_defn from sys.systrigger 
    where trigger_defn like '%adjusted_amount%'
```